# Facing an error in a PHP page which was working fine before i made some minute changes

Tags: php, html, mysql

Facing an error in a PHP page which was working fine before i made some minute changes.

The error cause is : $type = (int)$_POST['type'];

Error is : syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number(T_NUM_STRING)

**FUll code is as follows.**

```
<?php
require_once '../library/config.php';
require_once '../library/functions.php';


$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';

switch ($action) {

    case 'search' :
        search();
        break;

    default :
        // if action is not defined or unknown
        // move to main user page
        header('Location: index.php');
}


/*
search() function used to search hadrware, software with user given criteria.

*/`

function search()
{
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];


    $hsql = "SELECT a.hostname, a.username, a.cpumodel, a.servicetag, a.monitormodel, a.phonext
             FROM assets a WHERE a.username LIKE '%$name%' ";

    $ssql = "SELECT a.hostname, a.username, a.cpumodel, a.servicetag, a.monitormodel, a.phonext
             FROM assets a WHERE a.username LIKE '%$name%' ";        

    $data = array();
    if($type == 1){
        $result = dbQuery($hsql);
        if(dbNumRows($result) == 0) {
            header('Location: ../view.php?v=search&error=' . urlencode('No Hardware Found. Please try Again.'));    
        }else {
            while($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)){
                extract($row);
                $data[] = array('hname'       => $hname, 'uname'         => $uname, 'cmodel'         => $cmodel, 'stag'          => $stag, 'mmodel'          => $mmodel, 'pext'          => $pext);
            }
            $_SESSION [result_data] = $data;
            header('Location: ../search');              
        }//else
    }
    else {

        $result = dbQuery($ssql);
        if(dbNumRows($result) == 0) {
            header('Location: ../view.php?v=search&error=' . urlencode('No Software Found. Please try Again.'));    
        }else {
            while($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)){
                extract($row);
                $data[] = array('hname'       => $hname,
                              'uname'         => $uname,
                              'cmodel'         => $cmodel,
                              'stag'          => $stag,
                              'mmodel'          => $mmodel
                              'pext'          => $pext);
            }
            $_SESSION[result_data] = $data;
            header('Location: ../search');              
        }

    }endif;

}

?>
```

Comment: your code is in comment??

Comment: Can you show us your HTML codes?

Comment: Can you send your actual code!

Comment: My bad .i'll just post the full code

Comment: You execute the exact same query twice. Genius.

Comment: Yo Genius @Strawberry. Can we skip past how optimized my code is and actually look at the error i'm facing?

Comment: @Strawberry syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number(T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: It also gives a Line number

Comment: @Starwberry      $type = (int)${_POST['type']}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment above the function has a backtick character immediately after the closing comment marker. This is the cause of your issue.

If you remove this backtick, then you will resolve the problem. It still won't work as there is one other compile error in the code you've given, which is due to a missing comma at the end of line 64. If you fix that as well then program will run, you'll find that there are additional logic errors as well as security issues (but I'll leave those for you to find for yourself).

Comment: thank you Simba for help.Got all the other errors within minutes .About the security issues,it'll be locally hosted within a pretty secure network,still i'll work on that too.thanks fir the help mate!

Comment: The security issues are also bugs -- try entering a name like "O'Reilly" into your form and see what happens. This kind of thing does lead to severe security holes (and yes, you should respect security even for internal systems), but it also makes for good old-fashioned bugs. You really do have to fix it.  :)

Comment: Understood Cap!Thanks for the heads up. I'm on it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is after your comment. You open a backtick (most likely unintentionally) but dont close it. Just remove it and it should work again.
You even can see it in the highlighting.

```
/*
search() function used to search hadrware, software with user given criteria.

*/`

/* ^ there it is */
```

---

Also I´d like to point out, that your code is probably sql injection vulnerable. This for example:

```
    $type = $_POST['type'];
$name = $_POST['name'];


$hsql = "SELECT a.hostname, a.username, a.cpumodel, a.servicetag, a.monitormodel, a.phonext
         FROM assets a WHERE a.username LIKE '%$name%' ";

$ssql = "SELECT a.hostname, a.username, a.cpumodel, a.servicetag, a.monitormodel, a.phonext
         FROM assets a WHERE a.username LIKE '%$name%' ";
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel for the help,will look into the security issue in my code. Enjoy your Day!

Answer (score 0):

Your comment is not closed.

Put closing `*/` just before last curly bracket `}`

Or

If you do not want to have all the code commented then remove opening `/*` just after the
`function search()  {`

Comment: my bad,must have mistakenly placed code as comment while posting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with curly brackets in your variable name:

```
$type = (int)${_POST['type']}
```

Correct way is without curly brackets:

```
$type = (int)$_POST['type'];
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\test\search\process.php on line 28

Comment: pls, upload the latest version of your script.